# Minimum number of bags needed

Tags: algorithm

There are n items and length of each item is b. Different bar codes written on item consist of only 0's and 1's. We need to put items in the bag but with a condition. Most of the bar codes differ only in 1 or 2 bits. So we can only put an item into other bag if it has more than 2 differing bits from all the other items of that bag. 
How to find no. of bags needed.

CONSTRAINTS :

1 <= N <= 10,000

1 <= B <= 32

First line contains two space separated integers, N and B.

N : no of items to be carried, B : length of each bar code.

Example:

5 6

1 1 1 1 1 1

0 0 0 0 1 0

1 1 0 0 0 1

1 1 1 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0

where 5 is the no. of item and 6 length of each item.

Result:2

Explanation:

1st item has more than 2 bits differing from rest of all the items so it is in Bag 1.

2nd and 5th item have 2 bits differing so they can be grouped together.

3rd and 4th are also having only 2 differing bits so they can also be put into the same bag.

5th is having only 2 differing bits with all others but 1st, so 2,3,4,5 are all grouped together in Bag 2.

Comment: One more than the airline allows.

Comment: the result for this case would be 2...!

Comment: It's not an easy problem at all. what are the constraints. what is the maximum number of items?

Comment: is this an acm problem?

Comment: The way you've worded your description is very unclear. Maybe show what the answer is for the items you've listed in the question?  Specifically, which items go in which bags?

Comment: it is an acm problem :)

Comment: Which online judge you are using and how many problems did you manage to solve so far?

Comment: show us what you tried so far, if you don't have anything, here some piece of mind, create an array of sums of bits for every bar, sort the result array ascendig, and than iterate through elements and count diferences between two neighbor elements bigger than 2 , ex. sum array [6,1,3,3,1], sorted => [1,1,3,3,6], and as you can see there are only 1 difference > 2 (from 3 to 6), which mean there 2 bags

Answer (score 1):

First step is to make a Graph:

Nodes are the Items. Connect every pair of Items that are not allowed to go together!

Secondly, solve it as a Coloring Problem. There are a lot of [solutions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) on the interne!

Done ;-)

By the way it is NP Hard so [heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic) would be a good idea!

Comment: 2 differing bits from all the other items of that bag. are u sure that your solution work? because, as what I understood from you approach that the solution is the number of connected subgraphs. right? this statement make it don't work. please correct me.

Comment: Coloring is to give every neighbor another color ;-)
So all connected Items (which are not allowed to be in the same bag)
get another color. The coloring Problem trys to find the must less colors to do it => most less Bags needed! 
Maybe i mist something ...

Comment: take a look at this: http://poj.org/problem?id=1419 I managed to solve this but n is 100 maximum. what do you think.

Answer (score 1):

If we store number of 1's of each bar code in an array,sort it in ascending order,iterate through each elements and then count diferences between two neighbor elements bigger than 2 , ex. array [6,1,3,3,1], sorted => [1,1,3,3,6]
answer is 2....

would this solution work..??